# Why http://www.friend.ly can get information when I don't confirm

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I really surprise when use http://www.friend.ly site. I'm login Facebook and after go to http://www.friend.ly. I'm surprise because I don't confirm extended permission but this site can get email, address... Any ideas?

[image: My Information]
My Information



[image: Information get from friend.ly site]
Information get from friend.ly site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using the [Facebook Registration Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) which basically renders an iframe from Facebook's server.  Due to cross-domain browser restrictions, they can't actually access any of that data until you submit the form by clicking the register button.

Comment: +1, they don't get your email or any other data unless you submit the form, this is explained in the text at the bottom of the registration plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you read the section on the Graph API documentation about authorization you'll see that if they're using an OAuth 2.0 access token then they can retrieve any information that you have publicly available without your authorization.  You can see the examples below.

> The Graph API as such allows you to easily access all public information about an object. For example, https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor (Bret Taylor) returns all the public information about Bret. For example a user's first name, last name and profile picture are publicly available.
>
> To get additional information about a user, you must first get their permission. At a high level, you need to get an access token for the Facebook user. After you obtain the access token for the user, you can perform authorized requests on behalf of that user by including the access token in your Graph API requests:
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/220439?access_token=...
>   For example https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor?access_token=... (Bret Taylor) returns additional information about Bret Taylor.
>
> The Graph API uses OAuth 2.0 for authorization. Please read the authentication guide which provides details of Facebook's OAuth 2.0 implementation, how to request permissions from a user and obtain an access token.
>
> Getting an access token for a user with no extended permissions allows you to access the information that the user has made available to everyone on Facebook. If you need specific information about a user, like their email address or work history, you must ask for the specific extended permissions. The reference documentation for each Graph API object contains details about the permissions you need to access each connection and property on that object.

This quote is from the facebook documentation located here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: just update my question. I understand your idea. but I don't know why they can get extended information when I don't allow.

Comment: When I run your FB id with the access_token: https://graph.facebook.com/nguyenvietnamkhanh?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBANyy5GzqP7miMX1i5MAKS67cjf6lnY0dmCgoYdZAEBOxicKmiJg4Qg3OZBx4BtfbQuRdqXE9jJjBCYymz1oFgXS7soEQZDZD I see that there is an update time on there.  Did you make your profile more secure then?  Try clearing cookies/cache and check the site again.